# Drawbacks of running a RPC-enabled node

Tags: security, full-node, rpc, network, nodes

Besides increased resource requirements, why would someone not want to run a RPC node?

Comment: This deserves an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're putting your node out in the wild where everyone can see it.  The more attention on monero/your node, the more people will try to hack/attack it and use any information on the node to further hack/attack you or anyone else linked to that node.  For many foreign hackers with lots of time and a modicum of skill this is a risk free endeavor that will net them lots of untraceable magic internet money.